# Raspberry Pi 5 as Ubuntu Server 23.10 or 24.04?

Tags: server, upgrade, raspberrypi

I have at the moment an Raspberry Pi 4 (RasPi4) with Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 running stable as Web-Server and DNS-Server.
Working great but because of better performance I want to switch to Raspberry Pi 5 (RasPi5). But 22.04.3 is not supported on RasPi5.

My question is what is the best and easiest way to switch UbuntuServer to RasPi5?

- Is it possible to upgrade 22.04.3 to 23.10 on RasPi4 and the it‘s bootable on RasPi5?
- Or should I install new clean 23.10 on RasPi5 and then upgrade in April to 24.04 LTS?
- Or is 23.10 to experimental and I should wait till 24.04 was released in April and then doing clean installation?

I think clean installation would take longer then upgrade existing server, but I‘m not sure.

Thanks for your Input.
Greetings,
Alex

Comment: The Raspi 5 has different hardware than the Raspi 4. Not only the CPU, but also e.g. the I/O controller is totally different. So a SD-card which ran on a Raspi 4 will not necessarily boot correctly a Raspi 5.
Whether to install 23.10 now or wait unit 24.04 LTS is released it up to you - you have to decide whether you have time to wait or not.

Comment: Ubuntu *noble* (24.04) is an *alpha* system and thus off-topic until its released as a *stable* product which doesn't happen until April 2024. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS currently only upgrades to the next release (23.04) and doesn't have an upgrade path to *stable* 23.10. Ubuntu 23.10 is a released product, thus is *stable* however as already stated it isn't available for direct upgrade until 23.04 reaches EOL, thus making 23.10 the next release. LTS development takes place over two years; with 3 interim releases (22.10, 23.04 & 23.10 being views of progress towards 24.04, 23.10 the best view).

Comment: You should be able to dist-upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04 very easily, so personally I'd just go ahead and set it up on 23.10 and do an upgrade in a couple of months, yes, waiting for 24.04 to be released.  You should do a fresh install on new hardware and not simply exchange SD cards or something like that.  Best of luck.

Comment: On a recent install of mine I had to decide for one of my boxes; I intend for this install to survive for years, thus considered *noble* but I want *stable*. I opted for 23.10 for my own system, but as I was requested to QA a new *noble* installer package (*noble dailies hadn't yet started*) I used the 23.10 with *noble* installer for my install. Alas I didn't realize the *upgraded* installer would mean sources would pointed to *noble* (not *mantic*) so in my post-install checks I'd upgraded the installed system to be *noble*... My intention was 23.10 for my own install was *stable* 23.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend not messing around with unnecessary Ubuntu release upgrades on such a relatively new device. It's possible that upgrading from Ubuntu 23.10 to Ubuntu 24.04 before the recommended date when the first point release of Ubuntu 24.04 will be released in August, 2024 can lead to unforeseeable tragic consequences which can only be solved by reinstalling Ubuntu.

Instead wait until April and install Ubuntu Server 24.04 on your Raspberry Pi. A fresh install of an Ubuntu LTS version does not have the recommended date pushed forward to the date of its first point release like a release upgrade does. Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is a long term support release that is supported for five years until April, 2029 or for ten years with Extended Security Maintenance (ESM) which is free for personal use on up to 3 machines.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers an comments. So I will wait until 24.04 was released for a LTS fresh install on new hardware. Does that mean that for example 23.10 release is not as stable as 24.04 LTS release? So 23.10 is more experimental with new features?

Comment: It's not necessarily the same for all regular release, however this particular Ubuntu 24.04 release will include some new security features from Ubuntu 23.10 which have graduated and are now considered to be ready for the latest LTS release. With security being a paramount concern, Ubuntu 24.04 LTS will introduce enhanced security features, including improved firewall management, automated security updates, and extended support for Secure Boot and disk encryption, providing a fortress-like environment for sensitive workloads.